# How can I match lines with exactly three numbers?

Tags: regex, linux, grep, digits

How can I use grep to match 3 numbers in a file? My file looks like this:

```
123  
122    
222  
333443  
fdsfs5454353  
dsfsfjsk4654641
```

Note that some of the lines contain trailing spaces. I want to only match three digit numbers. I tried:

```
grep -E [0-9]{3} test.txt
grep -E '\<[0-9]{3}\>' test.txt
```

Comment: Do you mean numbers with exactly three digits, or each three-digit match in a string?

Comment: Your first example will break because it isn't quoted. Your second example works fine for me, but I offer a [simpler solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35374235/1301972) below.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '^[0-9][0-9]*' test|awk '{if(length($0) == 3) print $0}'
```

or if you have whitespace:

```
sed 's/[ \t]*$//' test|grep   '^[0-9][0-9]*'|awk '{if(length($0) == 3) print $0}'
```

(thanks @shellter)

Comment: I did it: egrep -o '\s([0-9]{3})\s' filename

Comment: Both the solutions work for me, are you sure there is no space etc. after hte numbers?

Comment: your awk solution will also match `abc` . Good luck to all.

Comment: ouch, use `awk '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/'` :-) ! Good luck.

Comment: hmm, awk '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/' did not work but this did egrep -o '\s([0-9]{3})\s'

Comment: @Gabriel : Ok, how about this ;-) `awk '/^[[:space:]]*[0-9][0-9][0-9][[:space:]]*$/' file`? Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Extended Regular Expressions with Bounds

[I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350222/match-only-3-numbers/35374235#comment58416461_35350222) if you meant numbers with exactly three digits, or each three-digit match in a string. [You replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350222/match-only-3-numbers/35374235#comment58437258_35350222) that you wanted only lines that contained exactly three digits.

Extended grep provides an easy solution for this. Consider the following:

```
$ egrep '^\d{3}\b' /tmp/corpus 
123  
122    
222
```

This uses a bound (also known as a range) to look for exactly three digits at the start of each line, followed by a word boundary. The word boundary will match trailing space or the end of line, ensuring that you get the proper match in either case.